# What happens if I take Clementine with me to Crowford?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

This contains episode 4 spoilers.

I chose to leave Clementine in the house instead of taking her with me. Upon coming back, a walker tried to go into the house, but Clementine killed it with a gun I left her.
Omid was sleeping upstairs.

If I had taken her with me, would the walker have killed Omid? Would she have been ok with the trip? It was really dangerous, but I assume she couldn't die as she is important for episode 5 at least.

What if I left her in the house but didn't give her a gun? Does Omid die?

Comment: Take Clem with you. She saves Molly from being attacked by a walker. If you don't take her, Clem gets upset and you will feel really bad later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take her to Crawford she will:

- stay in the room with Ben for the most time,
- shoot and kill the walker that attacks Molly after you miss your first shot, and
- ask for Ben to be saved, because he is her friend, if you tell her that she has a vote (I said yes) when Ben has his moment of idiocy and tells Kenny he is the one to blame, and his fate is up to debate. This also prompts Christa to revoke her vote.

Furthermore, Omid did not die. I have read but not verified that the walker indeed goes in the house, but should stay in the cupboard where the broomstick falls out.

Answer (score 2):

I tried both, and taking Clementine with me led to the least amount of people dying. Omid is fine, and Clementine saves Molly's life. Brie was the only person to die when I took Clementine.

Answer (score 0):

i took her with me she pretty much stayed in a room with ben out of the way...

Comment: What happened with Omid when you returned to the house?